# Ошибки при миграции yii2

Tags: yii2, миграция

Доброго всем дня. Пытаюсь установить [yii2-users](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/tree/master/docs) и на пункте миграции таблиц

```
php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class db does not exist'
```

Настройки db в config прописаны верно. Как победить?

Comment: Деталей мало. Очевидно, что чего-то не хватает. Неплохо приложить весь конфиг и стак трейс ошибки. Могу только предположить, для консольного приложения используется другой конфиг, в котором нет настроек подключения.

Answer (score 0):

Свою проблему я решил вот как.
в

```
vendor\yiisoft\yii2\yii
```

прописал

```
$config = require('путь к /config/console.php');
$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
```

До этого было

```
 $application = new yii\console\Application([
    'id' => 'yii-console',
    'basePath' => __DIR__ . '/console',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'yii\console\controllers',
]);
```

Я не знаю почему так, но помогло